# Making Blackberry act as modem and connecting to internet

Tags: modem, blackberry

I have tried and tried to no avail... I have downloaded berry4all and can't connect. Is there anyone who knows step by step how to connect? Even the help in Ubuntu points me in the wrong direction.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. I am flagging this for closure. Regards,

Answer (score 2):

Using the Blackberry as a modem device through a computer with Ubuntu can be achieved with a few simple steps:

Open the terminal from your menu or using the keyboard shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>, and then type:

1. **Download and install dependencies**

   ```
   sudo apt-get install python libusb-dev ppp python-usb
   sudo apt-get install python libusb-dev ppp python-usb python-wxgtk2.8
   ```
2. **Go to your home directory**

   ```
   cd ~
   ```
3. **Download the application**

   ```
   wget https://bitbucket.org/tcolar/berry4all/downloads/bbtether-0.3q.tgz
   ```
4. **Extract the downloaded file**

   ```
   tar -xvf bbtether-0.3q.tgz
   ```
5. **Access the newly created folder and run the application:**

   ```
   cd bbtether
   sudo ./berry4all.sh
   ```
6. **At this point you should have the GUI present:**

   - Go to the menu "File" -> "Preferences": Select "General" and un-tick the "verbose logging".

     Latter on, if no connection is established, you can tick it to see the logs.
   - At the same panel, select the "Modem" tab and from the "PPPD Config", select your internet provider.

     After selecting press <kbd>Save</kbd>
7. **Go to the menu "Modem" -> "Connect":**

   At this point you should have the device connected to your USB port.

   The first time the berry4all connects, it takes a minute or two, to perform a scan at your device and collect all the settings.

   Once the messages stop scrolling, your internet connection should be established.

   The last lines on the messages window should present your IP and DNS addresses.

---

**Notes:**

To disconnect, access the menu "Modem" -> "Disconnect".

Should not take more then 5 minutes to go from step 01 to a successful connection! :)

---

**About Berry4All**

> Berry4All is a free, open-source software for using (tethering) your Blackberry on alternative OS'es (Linux, OSX...) Formerly known as BBTether. The main feature is tethering(use as a modem) your blackberry easily, it is a simple python script/GUI and requires no compilation and has very few dependencies.

Visit the [website](http://www.berry4all.com/) and the [bitbucket project page](https://bitbucket.org/tcolar/berry4all/downloads)

Comment: "Connect script failed" is only message i can receive on my BB 9000 Bold, Czech Vodafone or Slovakian O2. Tried to play with config files, but no sucess.