# How do I set up a Blackberry as a modem without desktop software?

Tags: networking, software-installation, modem, blackberry

I'm a bit of a noob on Ubuntu but I love it! Our PC at work was pure garbage and so I decided to update to Ubuntu to salvage the old hog!

The only problem I have is that there is no internet connection at all (I agree, ridiculous!). Is there any way that I can use my Blackberry as a modem without having to download any additional software (as that would be impossible without internet connection)?

The one thing I thought I could possibly try is to download LinBerry or Berry4all on my home system, transfer to a USB stick and install at work off of there, but I'm not sure if that's possible. If so, can someone give me instructions on how to do the said task?

Any input is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: This link below to a similar question may help you out.

http://askubuntu.com/questions/38659/making-blackberry-act-as-modem-and-connecting-to-internet

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you enable WiFi mobile hotspot on your blackberry. As per the bellow link. Then connect via wifi.

http://mobile.pcadvisor.co.uk/how-to/mobile-phone/3441342/use-blackberry-as-mobile-wi-fi-hotspot/